# full join of the several data frames of nested data frame

Tags: r, join, nested

I have a nested data frame (as below) created after using map function and I have not untested it yet. Considering the example below, let's say I have 4 data frames nested (based on year) inside another data frame. In other words, the data frame that I have in my hand looks like df_nested. **How do I full join the data frames of each year separately (using map again) and then unnest them into a final data set?** I am trying to full join the data frames of the year 2010 (df1, df2) with each other and then full join the data frames of the year 2011 (df3, df4) and finally append these fully joint datasets.

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2010,2010,2010),id=c(1,2,3,4), name = c("A","B","C","D"))
df2 <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2010,2010,2010),id=c(1,2,3,4), age=c(21,22,25,29))
df3 <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2011,2011,2011),id=c(5,6,7,8), name = c("W","X","Y","Z"))
df4 <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2011,2011,2011),id=c(5,6,7,8), age=c(30,35,40,50))

df_netsed <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3,df4) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  nest()
```

Here is what I expect to see:

```
df_expected <- full_join(df1, df2,by="id") %>% bind_rows(full_join(df3, df4,by="id"))
```

Comment: `df_netsed` has no information about which data comes from `df1` or `df2`. How will you join them?

Comment: @RonakShah, I am assuming as they are nested based on the year, we can map a function like plyr::join_all() to them.

Comment: Do you have access to `df1`, `df2` dataframes? Or you only have `df_netsed` with you?

Comment: I can put the nested data frames in a list if that helps better or even unnest them.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** per OP comments
You don't actually need to nest, `group_by` should be enough:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4) %>%
  group_by(year, id) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), na.omit))

# Groups:   year [2]
   year    id name    age
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1  2010     1 A        21
2  2010     2 B        22
3  2010     3 C        25
4  2010     4 D        29
5  2011     5 W        30
6  2011     6 X        35
7  2011     7 Y        40
8  2011     8 Z        50
```

**Previous**
With `dplyr`, you can join each pair of data frames first, then `bind_rows`:

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2) %>% bind_rows(inner_join(df3, df4))

  year id name age
1 2010  1    A  21
2 2010  2    B  22
3 2010  3    C  25
4 2010  4    D  29
5 2011  5    W  30
6 2011  6    X  35
7 2011  7    Y  40
8 2011  8    Z  50
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrew_reece, however, in reality, I have several hundred datasets for each year so I have to be able to map a function for each year.

Comment: Thanks, however, what I am getting here is an appended data frame rather than a one that is joint

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `group_by` `id` and drop `NA` values for each nested data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_netsed %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, 
                ~.x %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(.fns = na.omit)))) %>%
  unnest(data)

#   year    id name    age
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1  2010     1 A        21
#2  2010     2 B        22
#3  2010     3 C        25
#4  2010     4 D        29
#5  2011     5 W        30
#6  2011     6 X        35
#7  2011     7 Y        40
#8  2011     8 Z        50
```

Comment: Thanks, however, what I am getting here is an appended data frame rather than a one that is joint.

Comment: What exactly is different between `df_expected` that you have shown vs what I have in my answer?

Comment: I do not get the same results

Comment: Can you be specific? What is exactly different in my answer and `df_expected` ?

Comment: for each id there are two rows, so the ids are repeated. so I have two rows for each id.

Comment: In `df_expected` there is only 1 row for each `id` 1 to 8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226547/discussion-between-seyed-hosseini-and-ronak-shah).